# Wake a process from sleeping - Erlang

Tags: erlang

Is it possible to wake a process externally in Erlang after it has been sent to sleep for infinity?

I would like to wake it from a different process which does hold the process ID of the process which is asleep.

I used this within the process which I want to sleep:

```
timer:sleep(infinity)
```

If it is not possible to wake it externally, what other options are available to me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rather than using `timer:sleep/1`, put the process into a `receive` so that it waits for a message. When the other process wants it to proceed, it can simply send it a message. Assuming the message matches what the `receive` is looking for, the first process will then exit the `receive` and continue.

Comment: Also note that one implementation of `timer:sleep/1` is `receive after Timeout -> ok end`.

Answer (score 1):

From the source code of this function:

```
-spec sleep(Time) -> 'ok' when
  Time :: timeout().
sleep(T) ->
    receive
    after T -> ok
    end.
```

you can find that `sleep` just let the process wait, do nothing.

if you want wake the process, you need send message to the sleeping process and do `receive`.